# Cannot access to a hidden folder

Tags: virtualbox, directory, netbeans, hidden-files

I want to access my database table, which is created in NetBeans. I'm looking for the `derby` folder:

```
student@student-VirtualBox:~$ sudo find / -name derby -print
```

and the terminal responses with:

```
/home/student/.netbeans/6.9/config/Preferences/org/netbeans/modules/derby
```

But when I'm opening the `student` folder, I cannot find any `.netbeans` folder as shown on the image:

http://postimg.org/image/no3m76flp/

How do I get access to the `.netbeans` folder ?

Comment: go into the student folder and press ctrl+H.

Comment: Thank you very much !!!. I have used hours to solve this problem, since I'm new to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can see `.netbeans` folder.

In Ubuntu, the file that it's name starts with "`.`" is hidden file.

In generally, you could not look hidden files in nautilus.

You can do it(let you look hidden files) with pressing `CTRL+H`(In menu, View/Show Hidden Files).